# html/css circular progress bar with image inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a circular progress bar around an image that should look like this :

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

I have tried making the circle fill but it just transforms into a spinner with the following code

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #21ac62;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: fill ease-in-out 3s;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.wrapper {
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/5T3p5sY/icon-3151974-1280.png') center no-repeat;
  background-size:50%;
}

@keyframes fill{
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery-plugin-progressbar.css">
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="loader"></div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You dont fill anything. All you use to animate is the rotation. You should animate the border-radius too

Comment: read this article https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/circular-progress-css/

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the goal without changing the HTML layout using `clip-path` animation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5T3p5sY/icon-3151974-1280.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #21ac62;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: fill linear 3s;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%);
  }
  12.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%);
  }
  37.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  62.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  87.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 50%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: This should be smoother:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5T3p5sY/icon-3151974-1280.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #21ac62;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: fill linear 3s;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%);
  }
  12.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%);
  }
  25% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 100% 0%);
  }
  37.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  50% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 50% 120.71%, 50% 120.71%, 50% 120.71%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  62.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  75% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, -20.71% 50%, -20.71% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  87.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  100% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 50% -20.71%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How it works: https://qu.ax/vaht.mp4

Comment: This is the second one: https://qu.ax/MuLp.mp4

Comment: This is great. How we can make it dynamic? Like the progress bar?

Comment: @MuhammadShahid I added a button to start the animation: https://jsfiddle.net/ratajs/gp9kq71f/3/

Comment: Thanks. Can you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518320/transparent-dynamic-circular-progress-bar-in-javascript-css-like-hollow-from-ins?noredirect=1#comment124658105_70518320

Comment: @MuhammadShahid Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ratajs/ugcqe8fb/20/

Answer (score 0):

For more Information and Full Explaination, Reach to https://dev.to/shantanu_jana/circular-progress-bar-using-html-and-css-1oda

```css
body {
  background:#d2eaf1;
}
.circle-wrap {
  margin: 150px auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fefcff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #cdcbd0;
}
.circle-wrap .circle .mask,
.circle-wrap .circle .fill {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle-wrap .circle .mask {
  clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 75px);
}

.circle-wrap .inside-circle {
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #d2eaf1;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 14px;
  color: #1e51dc;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

/* color animation */

/* 3rd progress bar */
.mask .fill {
  clip: rect(0px, 75px, 150px, 0px);
  background-color: #227ded;
}

.mask.full,
.circle .fill {
  animation: fill ease-in-out 3s;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@keyframes fill{
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle-wrap">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="mask full">
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mask half">
        <div class="fill"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="inside-circle">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-apple" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/>
  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/>
</svg> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```