# Transparent dynamic circular progress bar in JavaScript/CSS like hollow from inside or background image visible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I achieved the circular progress bar with background color like this:

[image]

But when i try to use this same code but without background color it becomes PI or rectangular. I want to achieve like this:

[image]

But what i have is:

[image]

If i try to remove bg color it becomes

[image]

I searched a lot but couldn't found any solution.

Here is the code that i am using for this.

```
<!-- Progress bar -->
<div class="bar-container">
   <div class="circular-progress" style="background: conic-gradient(#FFCAF0 <?php echo $percentage * 3.6; ?>deg, #003866 5deg);">
      <div class="value-container"><?php echo $percentage; ?>%</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS code:

```
.bar-container {
        background-color: #003866;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
    }
    .circular-progress {
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
    }
    .circular-progress::before {
        content: "";
        display: block !important;
        position: absolute;
        height: 84%;
        width: 84%;
        background-color: #003866;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .value-container {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #FFCAF0;
    }
```

Comment: Frankly, use an SVG, much simpler.

Comment: I tried using SVG but  couldn't achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `clip-path` to “cut out” the inner circle.

```css
.bar-container {
  background-image: url('https://invent.kde.org/plasma/breeze/-/raw/6d4fe7781790c69758be380324262261699894f7/wallpapers/Next/contents/images/1024x768.png');
  background-size: fill;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.circular-progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-image: conic-gradient(#FFCAF0 120deg, transparent 5deg);
  clip-path: path('M20 100 a80 80 0 1 0 160 0 a80 80 0 1 0 -160 0 L0 100 L0 0 L200 0 L200 200 L0 200 L0 100 Z');
}
.value-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFCAF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="value-container">33&nbsp;%</div>
<div class="bar-container">
   <div class="circular-progress"></div>
</div>
```

You can move the `background-image` property out of the CSS to edit it via PHP (but I guess you would have to use JavaScript to change it gradually).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to do it from last 2 days. You saved me!!!. -:)